# Mosaicking NetCDF files on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, netcdf, image-mosaic

I am trying to use ImageMosaic plugin on Geoserver in order to read NetCDF files. I follow this tutorial : https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/mosaic_config/netcdf_mosaic.html#

When I create ImageMosaic datastore everything is ok.

Here is my `indexer.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Indexer>
    <domains>
        <domain name="time">
            <attributes>
                <attribut>time</attribut>
            </attributes>
        </domain>
        <domain name="elevation">
            <attributes>
                <attribut>elevation</attribut>
            </attributes>
        </domain>
    </domains>
    <schemas>
        <schema name="ta">
            <attributes>the_geom:Polygon,imageindex:Integer,location:String,elevation:java.lang.Integer,time:java.util.Date</attributes>
        </schema>
    </schemas>
    <coverages>
        <coverage>
            <origName>ta</origName>
            <name>ta</name>
            <schema ref="ta"></schema>
            <domains>
                <domain ref="time" />
                <domain ref="elevation" />
            </domains>
        </coverage>
    </coverages>
    <collectors>
        <collector name="timeregex">
            <value>regex=[0-9]{6},format=yyyyMM</value>
            <spi>TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI</spi>
            <mapped>time</mapped>
        </collector>
        <collector name="elevationregex">
            <value>[0-9]{3}</value>
            <spi>DoubleFileNameExtractorSPI</spi>
            <mapped>elevation</mapped>
        </collector>
    </collectors>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="AbsolutePath" value="true" />
        <parameter name="AuxiliaryFile" value="_stac.xml" />
        <parameter name="IndexingDirectories" value="/var/lib/geoserver_data/coverages/data/_stac" />
    </parameters>
</Indexer>
```

My `databasestore.properties` :

```
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
host=172.17.0.2
port=5432
database=gis
schema=ta
user=docker
passwd=****
Loose\ bbox=true
Estimated\ extends=false
validate\ connections=true
Connection\ timeout=10
preparedStatements=true
create\ database\ params=WITH\ TEMPLATE\=ta
```

And my NetCDF ancillary file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Indexer>
<schemas>
        <schema name="ta">
            <attributes>the_geom:Polygon,imageindex:Integer,location:String,elevation:java.lang.Integer,time:java.util.Date</attributes>
        </schema>
    </schemas>
    <coverages>
        <coverage>
            <origName>ta</origName>
            <name>ta</name>
            <schema ref="ta"></schema>
            <domains>
                <domain ref="time" />
                <domain ref="elevation" />
            </domains>
        </coverage>
    </coverages>
</Indexer>
```

And an extract of my PostGIS database table ta :

[image]

My problem is that when I want to create a layer my list is empty :

[image]

I have no error logs.

Comment: turn the logging level up to GeoTools developer and see what it says then

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you, here is 3 suspicious logs : INFO [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Skipped file /var/lib/geoserver_data/coverages/_stac/ta.202005.aph2e5.GLOBAL_025.nc: File format is not supported. DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Trying to load properties file from URL:file:/var/lib/geoserver_data/coverages/_stac/datastore.properties
INFO [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Required key Levels not found.

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton I am new to Geoserver environment, turning the logging level up to GeoTools developer gave me so much more interesting logs !